# C++ - Pointer to class type

Tags: c++

Can I have a pointer to a class itself, not only a pointer to a variable?

```cpp
// I'm looking for something like this
class MyClass {};

MyClass* ptr = &MyClass;

MyClass* myclass = new *ptr;

// But not this
class MyClass {};

MyClass myclass;

MyClass* ptr = myclass;
```

Comment: The symbol `MyClass` is a *type-name*, you can't have pointers to type-names of any kind (would you expect e.g. `int* ptr = &int;` to work? It's the same thing).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that ?

Comment: No.    As you will have seen if you tried to compile that example.

Comment: `&MyClass` doesn't make sense. Classes/structs are not [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in C++. What are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with `new Myclass()`? Are you trying to use different classes based on some condition? This is not trivial with C++. You either have to use templates or polymorphism.

Comment: By `MyClass* ptr = myclass;` do you really mean `MyClass* ptr = &myclass;`?

Comment: And why not `auto ptr = new MyClass;`? That allocates memory for a `MyClass` object, constructs the object, and initialize the new variable `ptr` to point to thayt object.

Comment: This is typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe why you need this.

Comment: You probably need a `auto obj = make<MyClass>()` function. right?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Most probably he needs to use polymorphism and factory pattern.

Comment: A pointer refers to the location of an _object_. Types are not objects (but each object has a type). Therefore you cannot form pointers to types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some languages, types are first-class objects, meaning you can pass them around as arguments, introspect their class properties, etc.

In a language in which types are objects, you can refer or point to those objects.

In C++, types are used at compile time and then effectively cease to exist. They are never represented as first-class objects, and you can't really introspect them at runtime.

In a language in which types are not objects, you can't refer or point to those objects, because they don't exist.

---

For implementing a new language in C++, you're starting one level too low: before you can define a user-defined type in your new language, you need to know what type *that* type will be in your implementation code.

For example, in Python:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
```

defines two (empty) [*class objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions), called `A` and `B`. There are *not* two corresponding C struct types in the CPython implementation. There can't be, because the CPython interpreter was compiled (and is now a fixed sealed executable) before it ever saw our Python code.

So, we must instead define a single C++ type which describes a user-defined type in your new language. Each user-defined type will be an *instance* of this C++ type.

For example:

```
struct UserDefinedType: public Object
{
  std::string name;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> members;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Function>> methods;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<UserDefinedType>> types;
```

and in your new language, a statement like

```
class MyClass {};
```

would be implemented in C++ by something like:

```
case KEYWORD_CLASS:
  types.push_back(make_shared<UserDefinedType>(parser.getName(),
                                               parser.getMembers(),
                                               parser.getMethods()));
  break;
```

NB. we still haven't discussed taking a pointer to a class *inside* your new language. However, I made the `UserDefinedType` struct derive from `Object`, which means you could use them as Python-like first-class objects.

Comment: I am trying to make my own programming language. I was thinking I could have a vector with the types I have. So if I add a new type, I can just add it to that vector, but I would need to add the class, not an instance.

Comment: You mean, you're implementing your own language in C++? Or you're writing your own language above and it just looks like C++?

Comment: I'm writing it using C++.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can then implement my own types?

Comment: Probably the way I showed in my answer? I'm not sure what you think is missing.

Comment: Those are user defined functions, how do I make my own? Like should I make them in my new programmkng language or defined them in c++?

Comment: 1/ figure out what your language should look like. 2/ figure out how to implement that. They're two steps. I have no idea what your language is supposed to look like, or what part of my answer you think is a "user-defined function". I only wrote one line pretending to be in your language, the rest is all C++ and two lines of Python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196816/discussion-between-useless-and-physical-experience).

Answer (score 4):

Kind of.

[`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) is an object that "describes" a type. You can get one with the `typeid` operator.

However, since C++ does not support reflection, there's very little that you can actually do with it. For example, you won't be able to "dereference" it to generate some pointer-to-member.

You certainly cannot form a normal pointer, to a type.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I have a pointer to a class itself

No. There are pointers to objects, functions and members. There are no pointers to classes, or types in general in C++.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I have a pointer to a class itself, not only a pointer to a variable?

**No**.

A class is basically a type, and it doesn't make sense to point to a type.

As @SomeProgrammerDude commented: you expect e.g. `int* ptr = &int;` to work? It's the same thing.

PS: Maybe you are trying to practice the paradigm of polymorphism, read about it online..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pointer to compiler information about type  - `type_info` , returned by operator `typeid` . But looks like it`s not what you need. You should read about patterns  ["Factory Method"](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) and ["Abstract Factory"](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory) .

"Factory Method" pattern looks close to your code example.