# hiding a parent class but not the grandparent in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, using-declaration

Is it possible to skip a generation with regards to class visibility?

The following [works for gcc compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/WxY634EYP) but not [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/4148zrK4n) nor intel. They fail with `error: cannot cast 'C' to its protected base class 'A'`

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B: public A {int stuff() {} };
struct C: protected B { using B::A; }; // want to hide stuff from `B`, but keep the identity as an `A`

void call(A &) {}

int main()
{
    C c;
    call(c);
}
```

Is GCC overly accommodating in this case or is it correct?

The `A` and `B` in this example represent two classes that cannot be changed. For a solution to be usable, it has to be done in the `C` class.

**For those who want an unnecessary level of detail** ...

`C` is a class that provides new functionality by hiding and extending all the methods in `B` (all non-virtual).
Those `B` methods are designed to be chained together, with each one returning a `B&`.  There is a lot of existing trusted code that uses this chaining.  The idea is to minimally change such code from declaring the chained objects from B to C to get the improved functionality.

- A is `boost::python::object`.
- B is `boost::python::class_` ( no virtual methods).
- C imbues improved construction (`__init__`) semantics on objects by retaining the order in which the members are declared in the chain.

**workable solution (distasteful)**
I should come clean and admit that I can (and currently do) have it working by simply omitting the `protected` inheritance.  The C methods hide all the B methods.  But it seems brittle.
If a new method gets added to the library B class and new code uses it, there would be runtime errors.  I'd like to make the B methods inaccessible to turn those into compilation errors.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144778/c-pointer-to-class-type

Comment: @VictorGubin That's not relevant at all.

Comment: `using B::A;` should have no effect here. This looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: If the goal is to allow passing a `C` to `call()` (rather than being able to obtain a `A&` from a `C`, which strikes me as suspicious in general) one could provide a `void call(C &x) {return (A &)x;}`  and declare that function as a `friend` of `C`.

Comment: You could add a non-explicit conversion operator to `A&` to `C`. Being a member of `C` it could perform the cast from `*this` to `A&`.

Comment: Are you sure `B` needs to inherit from `A`? Needing to hide an intermediate parent seems unusual to me. Maybe `C` can inherit from `A` and `B` separately.

Comment: As for me, sorry if I missed something obvious in your question but if you want an instance of `C` to behave like a `A` but not like a `B`, then why does `C` not directly inherit `A` instead of `B` (`struct C : public A {...}`)? IMHO, your question could very well be a xy problem: you are not asking about what you want to do but rather about **what you tried** to solve what you want to do.

Comment: ^That, this sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and antithetical to inheritance.

Comment: @Peter , the `call` in this example is just a placeholder for various functions that live in the same library as A and B.  The C object needs to be treatable as an A..

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I tried the casting operator idea, but no compiler will choose that, giving 'inaccessible base' error.  re your second comment ... A and B are outside my control.

Comment: @Atmo,  There is substantial functionality within both A and B that need to be retained.  The C class is essentially extending the methods of B, but those methods are not virtual.

Comment: This is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62240).

Comment: [question about gcc incorrectly allowing what you have done aside] I'd suggest you need to revisit your design of `C`.   On one hand, you require protected derivation from `B` (which has `A` as a `public` base) and, on the other hand, you want non-`friend`/non-members of `C` to be able to pass a `C` to a function that accepts an `A &` argument, so insist `C` should be treatable as an `A`.   In other words, you're trying to work around limitations due to conflicts between two requirements that YOU have introduced - better to resolve the conflict (e.g. `C` derive `public`ly from `B`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is GCC overly accommodating in this case or is it correct?

This is a confirmed [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62240) which had a reduced example for the same:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C : B
{
public:
  using B::A;
};

int main()
{
  A *p = new C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Paragraph 16 of Section 9.9 of the Draft C++ Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#16) presents the following example:

```
class A {
private:
    void f(char);
public:
    void f(int);
protected:
    void g();
};

class B : public A {
  using A::f;       // error: A​::​f(char) is inaccessible
public:
  using A::g;       // B​::​g is a public synonym for A​::​g
};
```

In this context, it is clear that one should be able to program `B().g();` and have that statement call `B::g` in a temporary instance of B.

In the question, `B::A` names a type, so I should think that the effect of `using B::A;` should be to let a program access the type name `A` by references to `C::A` outside of `C` and its sub-classes.  For example, `C::A instance_of_A;` declares `instance_of_A` when compiled by both GCC and Clang.

However, that as a side effect, GCC exposes the protected base class `C::B::A` would seem to be a non-conformance.

To give this answer a little more context, consider this:

```
class C {
public:
    class A {};
protected:
    A a;
};
```

In the above context, the declaration `C::A a;` is acceptable, whereas a reference to `C().a` outside of the class is not.  In the example in the question, the type is exposed, but the instance of the base class should not be.

Ideally, to skip a generation of class visibility, one would make the visible generation virtual:

```
struct A { };
struct B: virtual public A { void stuff() {} };
struct C: protected B, virtual public A { }; // want to hide stuff from `B`, but keep the identity as an `A`

void call(A &) {}

int main()
{
    C c;
    call(c);
    return 0;
}
```

However, in this case Mark Borgerding has advised that it is infeasible to modify the definition of `B` to make `A` a virtual base class.  In this case, I suggest:

```
struct A {
    int a_data;
    int a_func () { return 0; }
};
struct B : public A {
    int stuff () { return 0; }
};
struct C {
protected:
    B b;
public:
    int& a_data = b.a_data;
    int a_func () { return b.a_func(); }
    operator A&() { return b; }
};
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the B class cannot be changed.

Comment: Have you considered something like `struct A {};
struct B: public A {}; 
struct C { B b; operator A&() {return b; } };`?